# Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure, while running on Mac OS

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, cypress

I am unable to run my cypress script on Jenkins and its on the local environment right now.

I am running the following commands on execute shell.

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/e2e/sample_test.cy.js"
```

While this is my project looks like:

[image]

After running 'Build Now', I am getting following error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52266/devtools/browser/b635687b-d873-45f5-8254-ae36106439dc
[31mCan't run because [95mno spec files[31m were found.[39m
[31m[39m
[31mWe searched for specs matching this glob pattern:[39m
[31m[39m
[31m[90m  > [31m[94m/Users/tp/.jenkins/workspace/SauceDemo Cypress Automation/[33mcypress/e2e/sample_test.cy.js[94m[31m[39m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Means cypress runner does open, but it closes down instantly.